# LongPress on List does re-order on iPad, but how to reorder on iPhone

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

With the following code, reordering the list works when long pressing,
but only on iPad, on iPhone the long press does nothing. how can I make it work on iPhone too?

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(objects, id: \.firstName) { object in
                    Text("\(object.firstName) \(object.lastName)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
        }
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        objects.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var isEditMode: EditMode = .active


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { object in
                    Text("\(object)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }.environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work for re-ordering the list, but not with a Long press. Also with this solution the 3 lines on the trailing side are always visible, it is not ideal.

Comment: @inatreecrown did you find a better way?

Comment: @hyouuu no, I used UIKit instead